# Locking custom list of users in SignalR Hub class

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR Hub subclass, where I keep a static list of users that joined the hub. Is there a need for locking that list in methods where it is used, and what is a proper way to do this - is this a proper way to do this?

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
    {
        private static List<HubUser> users = new List<HubUser>();
        public void Join(string UserName)
        {
            lock(users){/*some code to validate and store user*/}
        }
        public List<HubUser> GetOnlineUsers()
        {
            lock (users)
            {
                return users.ToList<HubUser>();
            }
        }
        //other methods such as GetUsersCount(), IsUserOnline(string User)....
    }
```

Comment: Read [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) article.

Comment: Is ConcurrentDictionary maybe a better choice then?

Comment: whats your mean about lock users?

Comment: exactly what happens when a user is locked?

Comment: I meant locking in order to control access to this list if concurrent connections try to call methods that work with user list - concurrency in multi-thread environment.